# Azure Traffic Manager 404 Not Found

Tags: azure, dns, azure-traffic-manager

I have deployed Azure Traffic Manager with Geographic routing mode enabled. Added to endpoints to the Traffic Manager (External Endpoints). I run two services (Let's say `Service A` & `Service B`) in two different AKS clusters. Ingresses are created for those two services accordingly.

`Service A` runs in AKS in `EU` region and has following Ingress:
Ingress: `myapp.service-a.my-url.com`

`Service B` run in AKS in `US` region and has following Ingress:
Ingress: `myapp.service-b.my-url.com`

In Azure Traffic Manager as mentioned above, I added two external endpoints (Let's say `Endpoint A` & `Endpoint B`)

For `Endpoint A` I added Ingress of `service A` which is `myapp.service-a.my-url.com`
Selected EU region as the geo-location
and
For `Endpoint B` I added Ingress of `service B` which is `myapp.service-b.my-url.com`
Selected US region as the geo-location

Finally created an ALIAS record in DNS:

Alias Record: `my-service.my-url.com > mytest.trafficmanager.net`

Now when I hit my-service.my-url.com it gives 404 Not Found. Is this because I created an ALIAS instead of CNAME for `my-service.my-url.com`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that:

- both services are responding properly when you call them directly;
- your traffic manager profile is using the correct path and port/protocol to check;
- when testing these DNS names using nslookup or Resolve-DnsName you receive the expected responses;
- the response code of the applications is 200 (the traffic manager expects it by default if the Expected Status Code Ranges field is blank) or any other code, considering that you have it defined in this field.

I would say that the problem may be related to be using the ALIAS, as it is not an standard and just some DNS providers normally make any distinction between CNAME and ALIAS records. The official documentation for Traffic Manager states that only CNAME records are suported and because of that CNAME records for the apex domain are not supported (it is not your case in practice, however as ALIAS records can be used in the apex domain, we can assume that they are not supported by Traffic Manager).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. And yes both services are accessible when I call them directly i.e. myapp.service-a.my-url.com and myapp.service-b.my-url.com BTW TM Endpoints also shows as online/healthy. But if I change the host part in ingresses to myapp.service-a.my-url.com instead of myapp.service-a.my-url.com and myapp.service-b.my-url.com then it starts to work properly. So now when I access my-service.my-url.com the application is loading properly.

Comment: So the record that is created in DNS (In my case it is my-service.my-url.com) which is pointing traffic to Azure TM also should exist in Ingress I assume?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think so. I have worked with a setup using two application gateways and the traffic manager endpoints was their respective public IPs and the ingresses hosts were the fqdn of the application that resolved to the Traffic Manager.